# How to straighten a bent tree trunk that occurs near the root

Tags: trees, tree-care

The tree is bent from the bottom of the trunk and is now growing bent. See

[image: Trunk Shape]
[image: Trunk bottom]

Comment: Is there a large tree to the left of the tree (behind it when you're looking at the tree from the road)?

Comment: There is a break in the bark below the graft that makes me wonder how viable the tree is. Watch out for sucker growth in the spring

Comment: @kevinskio Nice catch. Looks like it could be weedwhacker damage. The untrained seasonal help at our local parks kill a tree a year that way. Woodchips around it would prevent the damage, but they refuse to do that.

Answer (score 3):

It's where it's been grafted. Just leave it alone. [Here's](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/types/trees/how-to-stake-a-tree) some advice about how to properly stake a tree.